# Combine 3 columns from different sheets into a new sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 different sheets in my spreadsheet that I need some specific columns to be combined into a new one. The sheets are as follow:

Sheet 1

| Column Needed A | Alliance Mapped |
| --- | --- |
| id123 | Alliance 1 |
| id8952 | Alliance 2 |
| id4521 | Alliance 3 |

Sheet 2

| Alliances | trash column 1 | trash column 2 | identifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alliance 4 | test | some data | id45215 |
| Alliance 5 | test | some data | id454421 |
| Alliance 6 | test | some data | id45231 |

Sheet 3

| trash column | number | trash column | organization |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| some data | id41542 | some data | Alliance 7 |
| some data | id41 | some data | Alliance 8 |
| some data | id985 | some data | Alliance 10 |

So basically what I need to is to make like an union between the 3 sheets mentioned above, so in the final sheet it will look something like this:

| id | alliance |
| --- | --- |
| id123 | Alliance1 |
| id8952 | Alliance 2 |
| id4521 | Alliance 3 |
| id45215 | Alliance 4 |
| etc | etc |

I have created this script for getting data out off sheet 2:

```
function copySheet() { 
 var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
 var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet Final");

 var columns_to_be_copied = [4,1];

 for (var i = 0; i < columns_to_be_copied.length; i++) {
  var sourcerange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, columns_to_be_copied[i], sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1,1)
  sourcerange.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(1,(i+1)))
 }
}
```

But I don't know how to recreate this on a single code for the other sheets? Is there any way that it can be done?

EDIT:

New question, how can I use a different column if a string matches 'International' on the alliance column but if it doesn't match use the alliance column:

| Alliances | trash column 1 | trash column 2 | identifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| International | test | US | id45215 |
| Alliance 5 | test | some data | id454421 |
| International | test | JP | id45231 |

Hence the combine data will look something like this:

| ID | Alliance |
| --- | --- |
| id45215 | US |
| id454421 | Alliance 5 |
| id45231 | JP |

As you can see the new combined data frame has US and JP that exist on another column but this condition is only met if the International string is present else use the original column that is used on the code below.

Comment: This is a totally different question.  You should have submit it as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Get id and alliances

```
function combine() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  const shts = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"];
  const sObj = {"Sheet1":{id:1,alliance:2},"Sheet2":{id:4,alliance:1},"Sheet3":{id:2,alliance:4}}
  let oA=[["ID","Alliance"]];
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~shts.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(sh => {
    let n = sh.getName();
    sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().forEach(r => oA.push([r[sObj[n].id-1],r[sObj[n].alliance-1]]))
  });
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);

}
```

Output:

| ID | Alliance |
| --- | --- |
| id123 | Alliance 1 |
| id8952 | Alliance 2 |
| id4521 | Alliance 3 |
| id45215 | Alliance 4 |
| id454421 | Alliance 5 |
| id45231 | Alliance 6 |
| id41542 | Alliance 7 |
| id41 | Alliance 8 |
| id985 | Alliance 10 |

Comment: hey Cooper quick question, if I want to do an if function to check for example on sheet 2 the Alliance is called "Alliance 4" then instead of using column the alliance column to use the trash column 1 and for the others when this condition doesn't apply use the alliance column? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I've went over and edited the question, sorry English is not my first language

Answer (score 2):

- Create a configuration object with the columns needed.
- Manipulate the array using methods like [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const getData = () => {
  const config = {
      Sheet1: { id: 1, alliance: 2 },
      Sheet2: { id: 4, alliance: 2 },
    },
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    sheets = Object.keys(config),
    data = sheets.flatMap((name) =>
      ss
        .getSheetByName(name)
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues()
        .map((row) => [row[config[name].id-1], row[config[name].alliance-1]])
    ),
    outputsheet = 'Sheet[out]';
  ss.getSheetByName(outputsheet).getRange(1, 1, data.length, 2).setValues(data);
};
```